# transfer data from PLC to PC (MELSEC-Q Series)

Tags: plc, opc

I would like to develop an application to read data from PLC machine (MELSEC-Q Series). Currently, I am reading data using **kepware**. However, I have to specify which PLC address I want to read in advance. I want to build my own application thus I can specify at that particular moment which PLC address I want to read. How can I do that (any programming language is OK)? Is there any module to do that?

NB:

Actually, I want a function in a programming language like:

```
function (Read PLC Addresses X2, Y8 .... )
{
//read value of those PLC addresses 
// report to excel file
}
```

**I am very new in this field. So, correct me if anything is wrong.**

Comment: Typically you would start with the documentation of the interface adapter in use, or failing that, by (USB packet?) snooping the operation of the existing, unsatisfactory software in response to a variety of chosen API calls.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, is there any nice documentation how to do that? I could not find one and little help to start.

Comment: Any documentation would be specific to your unnamed interface adapter.  If it comes to reverse engineering an undocumented one, a web search will provide various guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [MX Component](https://ie3a.mitsubishielectric.com/fa/en/products/cnt/plceng/items/mx_components/) by Mitsubishi which an official API for communication with MELSEC-Q Series PLC (among others). The API is basically a COM layer that implements the MELSEC Communication Protocol using sockets (TCP or UDP) or serial communication.

It is possible to use the API using any language that supports COM, such as C/C++, VB6, C# and VB.NET

You can setup predefined configurations in the same way as a Channel/Device pair in [Kepware KEPServerEX](https://www.kepware.com/products/kepserverex/) or you could setup communication dynamically at runtime like you want to.

Just like Kepware KEPServerEX, the MX Component API is a commercial product.

Comment: excuse me, i know this thread is a bit old, however, may I ask is there any way/3rd-party developing tool to communicate with Mitsubishi PLC on Linux? As mx component is NT system only but I'd like to program my process control system on linux. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set-up multiple connections in Kepware, and call them as needed. In Wonderware (the HMI application I am most familiar with) each PLC then becomes a topic that you address to get the data.

Kepware has examples and sample code for VB here [Kepware VB Samples](http://www.kepware.com/Support_Center/app_vb_example.asp)